# Syntax error. Help with one small JS snippet :(

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys. I don't know much JS, but I wanted to do some quick work with jQuery.

But I've been staring at this for about an hour and I don't understand what I missed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#qty_6035').change(function () {
        var substractedQty, stockQty, remQty;
        substractedQty = (int) $('#qty_6035').val(); // missing ; before statement 
        stockQty = (int) $('#orig_qty_6035').val();
        $('#rem_qty_6035').html(stockQty-substractedQty);
    });
</script>
```

jQuery library is included at the beggining of the document.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript is a dynamic language so in order to convert a string into a number you could use the [`parseFloat`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseFloat.asp)/`parseInt` functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#qty_6035').change(function () {
        var substractedQty = parseFloat($('#qty_6035').val());
        var stockQty = parseFloat($('#orig_qty_6035').val());
        $('#rem_qty_6035').html(stockQty - substractedQty);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `parseInt` function, not `(int)` casting

Comment: Be sure to use the `radix` parameter to force base 10 when using `parseInt()` --- `parseInt($("#qty_6035").val(), 10);`

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript is not Java. `int` is a reserved keyword but doesn't have any functionality assigned to it, and you can't cast a value that way.

You probably want:

```
substractedQty = parseInt($('#qty_6035').val(), 10);
```

Answer (score 3):

Javascript doesn't support type casting like strong typed languages (C#, Java) do. To convert the field values (which are strings) to numbers you need to use the global functions [parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp) or [parseFloat()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseFloat.asp).

You'll probably also want to make sure the values are parsed correctly, in case a user entered some bad input instead of a number. Use [isNAN()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isNaN.asp) for that.